# How to merge (average/sum) duplicated objects in .json via jq?

Tags: json, bash, jq

I'm trying to get rid of duplicates that sometimes appear in my input.
Here is sample of data:

```
{
  "some": "very",
  "random": 0.228,
  "stuff": 31337,
  "people": [
    {
      "name": "carl",
      "height": "180cm",
      "wifes": 1,
      "sons": 0
    },
    {
      "name": "charlie",
      "height": "166cm",
      "wifes": 0,
      "sons": 2
    },
    {
      "name": "carl",
      "height": "180cm",
      "wifes": 1,
      "sons": 1
    },
    {
      "name": "carl",
      "height": "195cm",
      "wifes": 1.95,
      "sons": 12
    }
  ]
}
```

There is bunch of carl's, but only 2 of them are duplicates - name:carl & height:180cm.
For example I need to average amount of his wifes and sum his sons.
Here is expected result:

```
[
  {
    "name": "carl",
    "height": "180cm",
    "wifes": 1,
    "sons": 3
  },
  {
    "name": "charlie",
    "height": "166cm",
    "wifes": 0,
    "sons": 2
  },
  {
    "name": "carl",
    "height": "195cm",
    "wifes": 1.95,
    "sons": 12
  }
]
```

I tried using 'add' and 'reduce' but I'm pretty newb in jq ><

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The grouping can be achieved by `group_by/1` using [.name,.height] as the grouping criterion:

```
def sum(f): map(f) | add;

def average(f): sum(f) / length;

def consolidate:
  .[0]
  + {wifes: average(.wifes)}
  + {sons:  sum(.sons) } ;

.people
| group_by([.name,.height])
| map(consolidate)
```

### Output

The output is as per the given descriptive requirements:

```
[
  {
    "name": "carl",
    "height": "180cm",
    "wifes": 1,
    "sons": 1
  },
  {
    "name": "carl",
    "height": "195cm",
    "wifes": 1.95,
    "sons": 12
  },
  {
    "name": "charlie",
    "height": "166cm",
    "wifes": 0,
    "sons": 2
  }
]
```